# Getting Error H12 Request Timeout

Tags: node.js, heroku

Using satellizer for facebook login with nodejs ...
It's working in localhost but not in heroku app

How can solve this problem with heroku app, Timeout issue

> Error Response : config: Object { method: "POST", withCredentials: false, url: "/auth/twitter", … }
>   data: "\n\t\n\t  \n\t\t\n\t\t\n\t\tApplication Error\n\t\t\n\t\t  html,body,iframe {\n\t\t\tmargin: 0;\n\t\t\tpadding: 0;\n\t\t  }\n\t\t  html,body {\n\t\t\theight: 100%;\n\t\t\toverflow: hidden;\n\t\t  }\n\t\t  iframe {\n\t\t\twidth: 100%;\n\t\t\theight: 100%;\n\t\t\tborder: 0;\n\t\t  }\n\t\t\n\t  \n\t  \n\t\t\n\t  \n\t"
>   headers: function headersGetter/<()
>   status: 503
>   statusText: "Service Unavailable"

```
/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Login with Facebook
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
app.post('/auth/facebook', function(req, res) {
  var fields = ['id', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'link', 'name'];
  var accessTokenUrl = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/oauth/access_token';
  var graphApiUrl = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/me?fields=' + fields.join(',');
  var params = {
    code: req.body.code,
    client_id: req.body.clientId,
    client_secret: config.FACEBOOK_SECRET,
    redirect_uri: req.body.redirectUri
  };

  // Step 1. Exchange authorization code for access token.
  request.get({ url: accessTokenUrl, qs: params, json: true }, function(err, response, accessToken) {
    if (response.statusCode !== 200) {
      return res.status(500).send({ message: accessToken.error.message });
    }

    // Step 2. Retrieve profile information about the current user.
    request.get({ url: graphApiUrl, qs: accessToken, json: true }, function(err, response, profile) {
      if (response.statusCode !== 200) {
        return res.status(500).send({ message: profile.error.message });
      }
      if (req.header('Authorization')) {
        User.findOne({ facebook: profile.id }, function(err, existingUser) {
          if (existingUser) {
            return res.status(409).send({ message: 'There is already a Facebook account that belongs to you' });
          }
          var token = req.header('Authorization').split(' ')[1];
          var payload = jwt.decode(token, config.TOKEN_SECRET);
          User.findById(payload.sub, function(err, user) {
            if (!user) {
              return res.status(400).send({ message: 'User not found' });
            }
            user.facebook = profile.id;
            user.picture = user.picture || 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/' + profile.id + '/picture?type=large';
            user.displayName = user.displayName || profile.name;
            user.save(function() {
              var token = createJWT(user);
              res.send({ token: token });
            });
          });
        });
      } else {
        // Step 3. Create a new user account or return an existing one.
        User.findOne({ facebook: profile.id }, function(err, existingUser) {
          if (existingUser) {
            var token = createJWT(existingUser);
            return res.send({ token: token });
          }
          var user = new User();
          user.facebook = profile.id;
          user.picture = 'https://graph.facebook.com/' + profile.id + '/picture?type=large';
          user.displayName = profile.name;
          user.save(function() {
            var token = createJWT(user);
            res.send({ token: token });
          });
        });
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: It could happen if you don't have a connection to the database. None of the database queries will be called if that's the case and none of the res.sends inside the callback of those queries. You also have no checks for err, so who knows.

Comment: Db connection is working fine ... When I am running the same code from my local it's add entries to heroku Mongodb.
But when I am using heroku server .. it's thronging error "time out"

Comment: Thanks MikaS.. I fond the solution :) 
Connection was ok but query was something which isn't working as it should work ..